# Internal memory full even when all apps are linked

Tags: internal-storage, root-access, link2sd, internal-sd

I have an Acer liquid Metal rooted. I have already linked(with link2sd) almost all my apps, even some previously system apps, to my sd. The problem being that my memory is still full, the best I can get is 30 mb free and this, only for a while.

Is there any solution to that? Like bypassing what the phone thinks as being its internal memory?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with the [link2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info)? This includes some hints on what to look for. Also check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for more. After having that done, you might wish to [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46572/edit) your question with what you've tried and, if so, where you are still stuck.

Comment: @Squirtle What version of Android are you running? How much internal and external memory do you have?

Answer (score 1):

link2sd doesn't move data to your extra partition of SD Card. So even when you've linked all apps your internal storage will get filled by app's data.

In lnik2sd click the sort icon and select sort by data size. From there you can see which app uses most data and maybe clear them.